# Android App Login/HTTP Security

Tags: android, security

I have an app that is basically a front-end to dishing up some data from an external SQL server I'm running.

I need some sort of authentication for accessing data - so far I've sent username and passwords in the URL string (i.e. http://url.com/?username=user&password=pass&request=getData). Working perfectly.

I would imagine sending plain text user/passwords in the URL string would be pretty insecure (someone could be sniffing http traffic?). In what way could I secure this to remove visible user/password fields?

(FYI I'm using Node.js as a web-server and a mix of DB2/MSSQL/MySQL for databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options if you want to use the classical username/password authentication:

- **Transport layer encryption**

  This is what I suggest to use, because all you have to do is to install a certificate on your server side, and configure it to accept https requests. This way the whole communication will be enrypted, so the attacker won't be able to see any sensitive data. However it's important to mention that if you use self-signed certificate, then you have to import the related certificate chain to your application. Take a look at this topic on how to do that: [Android: how to do HttpPost with a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744517/android-how-to-do-httppost-with-a-certificate/22789559#22789559)
- **Application layer encryption**

  The difference here is that the ecryption happens in the application domain. So you would have to write the encryption/decryption methods. I do not sugges this, because it is really easy to mess up. However the advantage of this method is that the messages will remain encrypted no matter how secure the transport layer is. With transport layer encryption the messages will become unencrypted as they leave the encrypted channel. This is just a theoretical side-note, your messages will definately not leave the secure part of the communcation:)

It is worth mentioning that, using POST instead of GET does not have any added security if you make the request from code, since the attecker who sniff the connection could still see the posted (unencrypted) data. The POST method's main advantage is that it hides the paramters that would be shown in the URL otherwise. That is why POST should be used where the users access the service via a browser (that normally displays the current URL).

**As a summary:**

- use httsp
- optionally POST instead of GET.