# Using Httpsurlconnection to connect to server (SSL)

Tags: android, ssl, lets-encrypt, httpsurlconnection

I was attempting to switch from a self-signed certificate to a well known CA (by Let's Encrypted). The original code below works well to connect from the Android app to the server by first passing a JSON e.g. {"name": "xxx"}, while the server echoes the corresponding data.

```
 try {

      URL url = new URL(intent.getStringExtra(URL));
      HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setSSLSocketFactory(buildSslSocketFactory());
      conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      conn.connect();
      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
      Log.d(TAG,data +"sending to " + actStr(action) );
      writer.write(data);
      writer.close();
      int respC = conn.getResponseCode();
      if (respC < 200 || respC >= 400 ) { // OK is 200-399
          Log.e(TAG, "sending to " + actStr(action) + ", got response code " + respC + "=" + conn.getResponseMessage());
          conn.disconnect();
          return;
      }
      reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream()));
      makeStr = new StringBuilder();
      data = "";
      while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            makeStr.append(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "read"+data);
      }
      conn.disconnect();
 } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Failed sending to " + actStr(action) + ", cause: " + e.getCause() + " message: " + e.getMessage());
 } finally {
      if (reader != null) {
          try {
               makeStr.append("");
               reader.close();
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
 }
```

It comes together with a standard SslSocketFactory:

```
private static SSLSocketFactory buildSslSocketFactory() {
    // Add support for self-signed (local) SSL certificates
    // Based on http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa
    try {

        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
        InputStream is = App.getAppResources().getAssets().open(ManageActivity.certificate);
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            //System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            Log.d(TAG,"ca=" +((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

So, as to switch to site with trusted certificate, I keep the above code the same, but changing the certificate, which is a crt with the combination of intermediate certificate + site certificate according to nKn's answer here: [Android: how to do HttpPost with a certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744517/android-how-to-do-httppost-with-a-certificate) (I have actually tried on all the combinations among the root, intermediate and site certificates, and test on individual cert separately. But none of them worked). Unlike questions from the others, I don't get any errors saying I have an untrusted certificate or sth.

From the server site, it seems to receive a post request (I got a message from the error log), but there is nothing from the input, and therefore the app doesn't get any response from the server too. However, compared to self-signed certificate setting, codes from the server site are completely the same, plus when I pass the same JSON from the terminal with curl, it responses what I want, so I doubt if it is the certificate issue.

Does anyone know how to solve it, or I actually do not have to include the certificate or something?

Answer (score 0):

So I found what the problem is at the end.
probably the line

```
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

allows no data passing to the server (though I don't know why it works when I used self-signed certificate before...)

Also, SslSocketFactory is not required in this case.